# I want to show data's with similar id in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, api, rxjs

I have two APIs, its data have similar ids and different values. data is like this:

nights =

```
{
    yearNo: 2014,
    monthNo: 7,
    countryId: 6162,
    countryNameGe: "რუსეთის ფედერაცია",
    gender: 1,
    ageGroup: 2,
    nights: 26124560
},
```

visits =

```
{
    yearNo: 2020,
    monthNo: 10,
    countryId: 5967,
    countryNameGe: "აზერბაიჯანი",
    tourType: 1,
    gender: 1,
    ageGroup: 1,
    value: 7502768
},
```

I want to show related data (when countryIds are same) next to each other in table(html)

this is my component.ts

```
ngOnInit(): void {
       this.getQueryCountriesList().subscribe(arg => {
         this.countryDatas = arg;
       });
       this.getQueryNights().subscribe(obj => {
        this.nightDatas = obj;
      });
........
......
  getQueryCountriesList(){
    return this.http.get<any>(this.APIUrl + "/Visitor?tourType="+ this.tourType +"&year=" + this.selectedYear + "&month=" + this.selectedMonth +"&gender=" + this.selectedGender + "&age="+this.selectedAge);
  }
  getQueryNights(){
    return this.http.get<any>(this.APIUrl + "/Nights?tourType="+ this.tourType +"&year=" + this.selectedYear + "&month=" + this.selectedMonth +"&gender=" + this.selectedGender + "&age="+this.selectedAge);
  }
```

firstly I tried this way, but I get this wont work:

```
<tr *ngFor="let country of countryDatas; let nights; of: nightDatas">
    <th [id]="country.countryId + '1'">{{ country.countryNameGe }}</th>
    <td [id]="country.countryId + '2'">{{ country.value }}</td>
    <td [id]="country.countryId + '3'">{{ nights.value }}</td>
</tr>
```

Then I tried following:

```
const resulti = this.countryDatas.map((obj:any) => ({
    ...obj,
    ...this.nightDatas.find((o:any) => o.countryId === obj.countryId),
  }));
```

but it return empty array.

what can I do in this situation?

Comment: Use: console.log(arg) and/or console.log(obj) into subscribe method to see return of your rest api method.

Comment: @AndreMesquita It logs correct data.

Comment: Are you waiting for responses to come before merging objects ?

Comment: @Saptarsi No, I just want to place them next to each other

Answer (score 1):

Merge two data object inside subscribe.

`forkJoin` will emit data when a response has been received for all

```
ngOnInit() {
    forkJoin({
      countriesList: this.getQueryCountriesList(),
      nights: this.getQueryNights()
    })
    .subscribe(({countriesList, nights}) => {
      resulti = countriesList.map((obj:any) => ({
           ...obj,
           ...nights.find((o:any) => o.countryId === obj.countryId),
      }));
    });
  }
```

Comment: thanks, It returns correct joined data, but I cant use it in html, it doesnot show anything.                         `<tr (click)="SelectCountryData(rs.countryId,  this)" *ngFor="let rs of resulti;">
          <th [id]="rs.countryId + '1'">{{ rs.countryNameGe }}</th>
          <td class="text-center" [id]="rs.countryId + '2'">{{ formatThousands(rs.value) }}</td>
          <td class="text-center" [id]="rs.countryId + '3'">{{ formatThousands(rs.nights) }}</td>
        </tr>`

Comment: I checked with your html,it's working for me..is `resulti` is accessible in html?

Comment: it gave me this error "Property 'resulti' does not exist on type 'InteractiveMapComponent'." then i declared it in ts file, like this: resulti : any = [];. now I dont have any error, but I cant see data.

Comment: And you defined `forkJoin` inside `InteractiveMapComponent` ?

Comment: yes, I imported it

Comment: If it is possible provide `ts` and `html` file by removing other logic,then provide.Otherwise issue is not clear to me

Comment: You just log `resulti` value,check is it empty or not.

Comment: it is not, it give me good joined data, which I want to use. I added ts and html file in question.

Comment: provide your latest modified `InteractiveMapComponent.ts` file

Comment: I added it already

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this:

```
this.countryDatas.forEach((object:any)=>{
 if (object.id === this.nightDatas.id){
    this.similarDatas = object
 }
}
```

then on your HTML file,
just do this:

```
<th [id]="country.countryId + '1'">{{ similarDatas.countryNameGe }}</th>
    <td [id]="country.countryId + '2'">{{ similarDatas.value }}</td>
    <td [id]="country.countryId + '3'">{{ similarDatas.value }}</td>
```

Comment: It didn't work. when I log similarDatas, it tells it's undefined

Comment: Send the whole .ts file. There's something you've done wrong but I'm sure it should work